# What happens if I use OLS in a multiple (hedonic) regression where prices are systematically missing?

Tags: least-squares, econometrics, sample, iid

I am using a hedonic regression of (log) housing prices on a set of price-determining characteristics. I then use the estimated coefficients to estimate housing prices for observations not in my samples, specifically houses in rural areas (for which prices are not reported, but which report housing characteristics).

However, I recently learned that there are some questions surrounding housing price data used to fit the hedonic regression in the first place. It seems that the sample of houses for which price data was collected those not include houses in rural areas, because houses with the characteristics surveyed by the data collection do not exist in rural areas! I may be wrong, but I understand this wouldn't be a problem if houses in rural areas were excluded from the sample in 'random' fashion.

I characterize this situation as rural prices 'systematically' missing from the price dataset. But I'm having trouble understanding what OLS violation is taking place (not i.i.d.?) and what the implications are for my OLS results and how it relates to my regression eror term not being log-normally distributed?